# Why my angularjs filter does not apply some time when the object property change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have array of object say person which have two property name and hideMe. i have make a directive to add, remove person from array  and use filter to hide the person using property hideMe.

service

```
app.factory("personService", function () {

    var person = function () {
        this.name = "";
        this.hideMe = false;
    };
    var persons = [];
    return {

        add: function () {
            persons.push(new person());
        },
        hide: function (index) {
            persons[index].hideMe = true;
        }
    }
});
```

controller

```
app.controller("personCtrl", function ($scope, personService) {
    $scope.model = personService;
});
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" ng-click="model.add()">Add New Person</a>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name </td>
        <td>remove</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in model.persons | filter : { hideMe: false}" >
        <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="person.name">
        </td>
        <td><a href="#" ng-click="model.hide($index)">Hide Me</a> </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

when i hide the person by click on hideMe link some time it is not hide ????

here is the fiddle http://jsbin.com/kolaraliki/1/

Comment: I'm seeing what is happening with your code, but I haven't yet found a way to fix it.  I just wanted to let you know you are getting some attention, and I'll update with an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are experiencing this error is because of the use of `$index`.

`$index` gives the index of the current item in the iterator `ng-repeat`, not the index of the source element.  As soon as an item is removed from the array, the `$digest` triggers the `ng-repeat` to re-calculate, and `$index` of the items in the `ng-repeat` are re-calculated.  Thus, if you have 3 items in your array, at `0,1,2` but item `1` is hidden, you would expect your `ng-repeat` would have 2 items, `0,2` but it actually has `0,1`.  clicking to hide `2` would actually try to hide `1` in the array, which is already hidden.

instead of using `$index`, try instead `model.hide(model.persons.indexOf(person))` to get the actual array index instead of the iterator index.

I forked your jsbin with an example: http://jsbin.com/jecosofequ/2/edit

Comment: Good explanation about the use of $index.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have already filtered only those persons who have `hideMe` value as true to be shown and by clicking link which calls `hide()` you are simply setting `hideMe` value as true for second time. You can simply fix this by changing that filter to be `filter: { hideMe: false }` in your ngRepeat and then it should work. Because it would show's only those objects which `hideMe` values are false.

Comment: sorry i have put hideMe: true instead of hideMe: false. its a typing mistake.

Comment: @VinodPatidar: thank you for clarification. Can you make fiddle of your code?